# Using Possessive Articles

Tags: grammaticality, possessive-pronoun

Today a friend asked me this question.

Machen Ihnen _______(1) Kochkurse(die) spaß, Herr Leichter? - Oh ja, die Teilnehmer haben viel spaß mit ihrem Kollegen und probieren gern ______(2) Gerichte(die).

I think the answer to 1 is "Ihre" as in "Nominative/Plural/Sie(Formal) " beacuse the Kochkurse is doing the work of making(machen) Herr Leichter fun. Thus, making it the subject.

As for the answer to 2, is "ihre" as in "Akkusative/Plural/sie(them)" since the probieren verb is accusative verb.

But I could not tell him this because I was not sure myself. And answer could be "Akkusativ/Plural/Sie - Ihre" or not.

I have sufficient understanding of using possessive articles with preposition(all cases) and I thought I had sufficient understanding of subject, direct object, indirect object.

But this sentence as simple as it seems  suddenly started being so complex. Any explanation that could clarify my confusion would be great.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Machen Ihnen die Kochkurse **S**paß, Herr Leichter?

You can replace *die* by **meine**, **seine**, **ihre**, **Ihre**, **unsere**.

> Machen Ihnen meine Kochkurse Spaß, Herr Leichter?

I ask Herrn Leichter about my cooking lessons.

> Machen Ihnen seine/ihre Kochkurse Spaß, Herr Leichter?

I ask Herrn Leichter about the cooking lessons another man/woman organizes.

> Machen Ihnen Ihre Kochkurse Spaß, Herr Leichter?

I ask Herrn Leichter about the cooking lessons he himself organizes or attends.

> Machen Ihnen unsere Kochkurse Spaß, Herr Leichter?

I ask Herrn Leichter about the cooking lessons we attend together.

For the second sentence, it's similar.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.